# How can I automatically group each shape with the text inside it for a huge collection of rectangles?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, autocad

I have a `.dwg` (AutoCad file) map full of fields (rectangles) that I'm manipulating with Illustrator. Each rectangle has a text inside it that indicates its number. The problem is that there is no association between the rectangle and its number and that's what I'm trying to do. Also the order or drawing is not the same, when I check the layers.

Is there a way with Illustrator that can group each rectangle to the text inside it and this for all the fields? It is possible manually, but impossible to do it for every single field: about 40,000 rectangles.

I guess the approach should have something to do with "closeness" since it's the only data that tells us the correspondence between a rectangle and its number.

Comment: What is the final goal of grouping the rectangle with its number? There might be another way of achieving what you want in the end.

Comment: Is there any way to use AutoCad to export the file in a more usable format? When I've been presented with similar things in the past (after crying in the bathroom for a few minutes), I've found it easier to re-create the drawing from scratch in Illustrator (although I've never had to do something with so many elements).

Comment: Following @Voxwoman comment: could you maybe export it as an `.svg` file? Then a scripting solution would be possible that places rectangle and text objects with proximate x,y coordinates in a [g-element](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html), essentially grouping them.

Comment: Illustrator can open DWG nativity, that's mean it can read blocks, Xref,shapes and objects. So you may save your DWG and group your rectangles with blocks and xref and test it which way could be imported into illustrator well.

Comment: This is an easy task if created within Illustrator. However, if importing some other file, there's nothing easy to accomplish what you are after.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Here is more information: @Bart , the final goal is to have the number, referencing the rectangle so that in an application I can enter a number to display the corresponding rectangle. Voxwoman : you are right but it's not possible in this case because the coordinates of each rectangle are real and very precise: not possible to re-draw the whole map I guess. I did export the file to .svg I have the XML code. I believe that a scripting solution is possible as Bart mentioned, but I was wondering if there might be an easier/faster way via Illustrator. Thank you for ur help!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that can help you do this. You can get it from here:
http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/index.php

Download the "[GroupOverlappingObjects.js](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/groupOverlappingObjects.js)" to your Illustrator scripts folder.
It should be someplace like this on PC:

"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Illustrator CS\Presets\Scripts"

or Mac

"/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC 2015/Presets/en_US/Scripts"

Open/reload Illustrator and select all the objects that you wish to group. Then go to:

File > Scripts > GroupOverlappingObjects

A dialog box should appear to tell you how many groups were created. Checking the layers box should show your newly grouped items.

I tested this in Illustrator CC 2015.

*Contents of javascript (29/07/2015):*

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Group Overlapping (Beta) -- CS, CS2, CS3
//>=--------------------------------------
//
//  Groups all overlapping objects in selection into discreet groups.
//  The definition for 'overlaping' is based on objects bounding boxes, not their actual geometry.
//  Each new groups zOrder is determined by the depth of the front-most object in each group.
//  There is no limit to the number of groups created.
//  Any non-overlapping objects are ignored.
//
// Note: Currently, this is not very efficient code. It works well on small groups (less than 120 objects)
// and works faster on smaller groupings. Running this on a huge number of objects will likely crash illustrator.
// It serves my purposes, but test it's limits on your machine, and use at your own risk. 
// On a 2.53GHz P4, a group of 100 objects took 20 seconds with 2 groups.
//  
//
//>=--------------------------------------
// JS code (c) copyright: John Wundes ( john@wundes.com ) www.wundes.com
//copyright full text here:  http://www.wundes.com/js4ai/copyright.txt
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

//this little section is just for testing
//the number of times each function is called.
var testmode = 0;
var t1=t2=t3=t4=t5=t6=t7=0;
var testmsg="";
//
//
//
var go=true;
if(selection.length>120){
go = confirm("You have selected "+selection.length+" objects. It is highly recommended that you select less than 120 objects at a time. Do you want to continue anyway?");

}
if(selection.length>1 && go == true){
    var groups=0;
    var slen = selection.length;
    var hitList= new Array(slen);
    var groupArr = new Array(slen);
    // for each element in selection
    for (var sx=0;sx<slen;sx++){ 
    //t6++; //---------------------------------------------loop tracker
        var tArr = new Array(0);
            // for each element in selection (again)
        for (var si=0;si<slen;si++){
            //t7++; //-------------------------------------loop tracker
            groupArr[sx] = tArr;
            //note each object hits itself once.
            if(hitTest(selection[sx],selection[si])){
                    groupArr[sx].push(selection[si]);
            }
        }
    } 

minimize(groupArr);
var zError = 0;
var gaLen = groupArr.length;
for(var each=0;each<gaLen;each++){
    if(groupArr[each].length>1){
        groupArr[each].sort(sortBy_zOrder);
    }
if(zError==1){
    alert("cannot read some objects zOrderPosition");
}
//alert("halftime");
for(var each =0;each<gaLen;each++){ 
    t1++; //----------------------------------------------loop tracker
    if(groupArr[each].length>1){
        groups++;
    groupAll(groupArr[each]);
    }
}
//
//---all done with main code, now display statistics if you care...
//

testmsg="\nObjects processed: "+t1+"\nObjects grouped: "+t2+"\nObjects ignored: "+(t1-t2);

if(testmode==1){
testmsg+="\n\n---testmode data---\nhits compared: "+t5+"\nfunction 'minimize' called: "+t3+
"\nitems tested within 'minimize': "+t4;
"\nelements: "+t6+
"\nelements*elements: "+t7;
}

var x=0;

while(x<selection.length){

    if(selection[x].name == "wundes_GO_group"){
         selection[x].name = "";
    }else{
        selection[x].selected = false;
          x--;
    }
    x++;
}
redraw();
alert(groups+" groups created.\n----------------"+testmsg);
}


}
//----------------------------------------------------------->
//--------------------------------functions------------------<
//----------------------------------------------------------->
function sortBy_zOrder(a, b) {
        if(a.zOrderPosition==undefined){
            alert(a.zOrderPosition);
            zError = 1;
             return 0;
        }
        var x = Number(a.zOrderPosition);
        var y = Number(b.zOrderPosition);


return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
}

function groupAll(arr){
    var tempGroup = arr[0].parent.groupItems.add();

    tempGroup.move(arr[0],ElementPlacement.PLACEBEFORE);
    var max = arr.length;
    for(var i=max-1;i>=0;i--){
        t2++; //-----------------------------------------loop tracker
        arr[i].move(tempGroup,ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
    }
        //name the object for selection at end... (will be removed later)
        tempGroup.name = "wundes_GO_group";
        tempGroup.selected = true;

}
//---------------hitTest functions ---------------
function hitTest(a,b){
    var OK=0;
    if(isWithinX(a,b) || isWithinX(b,a)){
        OK++;   
    }
    if(isWithinY(a,b) || isWithinY(b,a)){
        OK++;
    }
    if (OK<2){
        //alert("miss.");
        return false;
    }else{
        //alert("Hit!")
            return true;
    }
}
function isWithinX(a,b){
    var p1 = a.geometricBounds[0];
    var p2 = b.geometricBounds[0];
    if(p2<=p1 && p1<=p2+b.width){
         return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    } 
}
function isWithinY(a,b){
    var p3 = a.geometricBounds[1];
    var p4 = b.geometricBounds[1];
    if(p3>=p4 && p4>=(p3-a.height)){
        return true;
    } 
        return false;
}

/*
//-----------------------------------OK, finding groups is done, now do the grouping---------------
*/

function itemize(a){
 var out="";
 return(a.join("\n"));
}
function minimize(arr){
for(var e in arr){
    t3++; //-----------------------------------------loop tracker
    for (ot in arr){
        t4++; //-------------------------------------loop tracker
        if(arr[e]!=arr[ot]){
        //if it's not THIS element,
        //test for overlaps
        if(overlaps(arr[e],arr[ot])){
            merge(arr[e],arr[ot]);
            arr[e] = new Array(0);
            minimize(arr);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}

}
function merge(a,b){
    var alen = a.length;
    for (var all=0;all<alen;all++){
        if(contains(b,a[all])){
            //do nothing
        }else{

         b.push(a[all]);

        }
    }

}
function contains(ar,i){
    for (var all in ar){
        if (ar[all] == i){
            return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}


function overlaps(ar1,ar2){
    for (var each in ar1){
        t5++; //------------------------------------loop tracker
        if(contains(ar2,ar1[each])){//
            return true;
        }
    }
return false;
}
```