# Group every object to its background icon

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to group all objects at once to their background (If all selected at once)? 
For "Asset Export"when exporting huge amount of icons. 
[image]

Otherwise i have to select every object, like this to group it to its background.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I automatically group each shape with the text inside it for a huge collection of rectangles?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46889/63979) The answer here contains a script that can probably do what you want.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks you are real mvp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to select all objects and have them group the way you want it.
This sort of *smart* grouping feature doesn't (yet) exist in Illustrator, though with the current technology, it's probably something they can accomplish relativley easily.

I would suggest to at least using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to quickly group each selection (rather than right click).

The ungroup shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, i'm using Keyboard shortcuts right now, i was wondering if there was automated way.